# How to find and replace <br> tag in a string?

Tags: java, html, if-statement

I need to find if a string contains a `<br>` tag and I wish to replace the tag with a space instead I have tried this but to no avail:

```
        if (cell.contains("<br\\/>")) {
            cell = cell.replace("<br\\/>"," ");
        }
```

Comment: Why not just `cell = cell.replace("<br>", " ");`?  No escaping or if-statements are required for this.

Comment: @azurefrog Thank you, I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Not sure why but

`cell = cell.replace("<br>"," ");` didn't work for me.

This on the other hand this did

`cell = cell.replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]"," ");`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to escape special characters in your input `String`, but that's not required; the [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method on `String`:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the **literal target sequence** with the specified literal replacement sequence.

so a simple

```
cell = cell.replace("<br>"," ");
```

will replace every instance of `"<br>"` with `" "` in your string.

This is in contrast to [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which both take a regular expression and a replacement.

Also, there's no need for the if-statement.  If the target sequence is not found, `replace()` will simply return the original string, so the if is redundant.